# Trying to pass a populated array to my res.render. Not sure how to make a proper async callback

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, asynchronous, express

I am trying to write up something that takes a lists of IPs from a database, and then retrieves information from the servers, populates an object, and then passes that object to an array. I seem to be able to make each object populate, and that I can tell, it's being passed to the array, but when the webpage loads (or I do a console log of my array), it's always empty. I have reason to believe it has to do with this being written up synchronously. I'm still new to async/sync differences and functionality. I tried a few different methods I thought would work, but no matter what, I seem to be getting an empty array.

```
app.get('/', function (req,res) {


//1) Read out the entries from the database.
db.all('SELECT * FROM servers', function (err,rows) {
        var servers = rows;
        var serverList = [];


    //2) parse each one with a for Each from the steamServerStatus
        servers.forEach( function (server) {

                var ip = server.ip;
                var port = server.port;
                //3) Populate an array with each object
                steamServerStatus.getServerStatus(ip, port, function (serverInfo) {
                        var serverToken = {};

                        serverToken.ip = ip;
                        serverToken.serverName = serverInfo.serverName;
                        serverToken.playerCount = serverInfo.numberOfPlayers + "/" + serverInfo.maxNumberOfPlayers;
                        serverList.push(serverToken);       
                }); // end serverstatus
    }); // end forEach

    //4) Pass that out to our res.render
        res.render('pages/index', { servers: serverList });
}); //End db.all
```

The array should be getting populated, right? And if it is just an async issue, what would be a good implementation to make the execution order work?

Answer (score 0):

You can't use functions that fetch results asynchronously in a loop like that. You should instead be using something like [`async.each`](https://github.com/caolan/async#each):

```
var serverList = [];
async.each(servers, function eachServer(server, done) {
  server.getItsThing(function onThing(err, thing) {
    if (err) return done(err);
    serverList.push(thing);
  });
}, function onAllServersDone() {
  res.render('pages/index', { servers: serverList});
});
```